# how to specify that T implement Comparable<T>?

Tags: java

I get error: `Cannot resolve method 'sort(java.util.List<T>, boolean)'` in case:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyArray arr = new MyArray();
        arr.set("b");
        arr.set("a");
        arr.sort();
    }
}
class MyArray<T> {
    List<T> myList;
    
    MyArray(){
        myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    
    public void set(T val) {
        myList.add(val);
    }
    
    public void sort() {
        ListFunctions.sort(myList, true);
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}

class ListFunctions {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> array, boolean ascending){
        if (ascending){
            array.sort(null);
        }
        else {
            array.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is in line `ListFunctions.sort(myList, true)`. I can't convert this way `(List)myList`, because meaning of constraint `T extends Comparable<T>` is lost.
I see examples of code where T need to implement Comparable interface, but in my case I can't specify class. I implicitly use `List<String>`

Comment: Since you're calling `ListFunctions` with a constant to describe the sort direction you may as well just call `list.sort(Comparable.reverseOrder());` or just pass the Comparator as an argument.   I also suggest you not call `List<T>` an `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class

```
class MyArray<T>
```

Should simply be

```
class MyArray<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

If you don't do that, you may potentially pass an out of bound type to your utility function which the compiler will reject accordingly.

```
MyArray arr = new MyArray();
```

will hence become

```
MyArray<String> arr = new MyArray<>();
```